# Hyper-v virtual machine acting as two separate vm's

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I have a Hyper-V virtual machine (vm1) that has two separate instances of itself. I can log into what should be the same VM (vm1) through Hyper-v and RDP (Remote Desktop Connection) with the same ip or the same name and it does not warn me that I am on the same VM in a different location like the other 2 correct VM's running (vm2,vm3) when logged in at the same time. Additionally, they do not share the same files between the two connections like my other working machines proving that they are acting separately. Some more information that may be helpful, previously my network adapter stopped working on my machine hosting the three Hyper-V virtual machines (vm1,vm2,vm3) so I switched over to the second network adapter and added a new virtual external switch (vs2) for the new network adapter location. This solved the network issues but then vm1 applications that were running no longer worked, so I had to leave vm1 on the previous switch (vs1). What is going on?

Comment: What do you mean by `through Hyper-v and RDP at the same time`?

Comment: I get two different VM's when I connect through hyper-v virtual machine connection and Remote Desktop Connection (RDP).

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. Perhaps you can clarify it.